# Did this character die while fighting Thanos?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

While defending Vision from Thanos,

1. Thanos crushed the War Machine suit.
2. Natasha was under a huge rock pillar.
3. Banner was fused into huge rocks.
4. Captain America apparently took unbearable punch By Thanos on his head.

When Thanos uses Time Stone to bring back Vision, He also reversed the things happened there.

1. Rhodey's suit doesn't looked crushed.
2. Banner wasn't fused in stones.
3. Nat was no longer in Pillars.
4. Cap showed no sign of injuries from a blow.

So, my question is, **was Captain America killed by Thanos and resurrected when time was reversed?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too broad and among some other reasons is it doesn't look like a question but OP is trying to make a discussion. from his own comment **I am not sure that's why i asked the question here. – Aditya Shah**. Also it seems OP wasn't giving any attention to the movie at all

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**There's no indication of this in the film.**

First, it's worth noting that time only rewound *around Vision.* Note, for example, that Wanda was able to scream "NO!" and lunge at Thanos while he was restoring Vision. If he'd been rewinding time everywhere, or even just over the entire battlefield, she would have been rewound along with everyone else and wouldn't have been able to do that.

I don't remember what happened to War Machine, but Thanos used the Reality Stone to immobilise Black Widow and Banner. It would appear that he undid the illusions when he left, just as he did when he left the ruins of Knowhere and restored Drax and Mantis.

As for the punch, [this transcript](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War)<sup>1</sup> describes it thusly:

> [...Thanos looks very briefly impressed at Cap's efforts before slamming a fist into his head and rendering him insensible]

"Insensible" is not dead. At most, he was knocked unconscious briefly. Either way, **nothing in the script indicates that Thanos' punch killed Captain America.**

---

<sup>1</sup>I don't know how accurately this matches the shooting script, but it's the most complete transcript I can find.

Comment: +1 Even if Thanos' punch would kill a normal human, Cap is notably stronger than the average human due to his super soldier serum injection.

Comment: Is it possible to just rewind time for just 1 person ?

Comment: @AdityaShah yes, think about the apple in Doctor Strange ... he's able to reverse and accelerate time for the apple on the table when experimenting with the Time Stone.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for clearing the confusion and also for the opening the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Captain America did not die from that punch. One of the last shots of the movie is Cap sitting on the ground as the remainder of the team gathers around and that's when he says his iconic

> "Oh god.."

line.

Here's a [crappy screengrab](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-606742facd49783bf5df04b21a2175a8) that also shows everyone else standing around:

Comment: You've misunderstood the (admittedly confusing) question.  He's speculating that Captain America dies from the punch and is brought back to life when Thanos reverses time to bring back Vision and the Mind Stone. He's not disputing that Captain America is alive at the end of the movie.